# After delete event is not working

Tags: apex, soql, salesforce1-app, record-type

got a requirement like to calculate average in account based on particular record type of case. My requirement is:

I have a field called ARP in account currency. I want to calculate overall average of ARP field in particular record type called customer order whether Case details either new or add-on.

So I'm trying write a trigger a trigger.

Everything is working but after delete event is not working means.

> Example when i create a case with ARPU will be 21.And if i delete the
>   case it's still showing 21 in account level.Even i am trigger.old in
>   trigger to handler class.

My trigger code

```
trigger ForARPU on case (after insert,after update,after delete) 
   {  

    if(Trigger.isAfter && trigger.isDelete) 
    {     
        //It will call a static method called ARPUInsert in ARPUCases class.
        ARPUCases.ARPUDelete(Trigger.Old);

    }
   }

    public static void ARPUDelete(List<Case>  CaseTriggers) 
    {
        /** 
         * This method is to caluclate average of all ARPU amounts with case have customer order recordtype
         * as well as case details with either ADD-On (OR) New Subscription and update in related account
         * field called ARPU. 
         * This method will fire only when any case with record type called customer order is deleted. 
        */

        if (Trigger.IsDelete)
        {
            for (Case s : CaseTriggers)
            {
                if(s.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId && s.Case_Details__c =='New Subscription' || s.Case_Details__c =='Add On' ) 
                {
                    // Loop through and add caseId's to the list.
                    CaseIDs.add(s);
                }
            }
 system.debug('Case:IDS ' + caseIds);
            /** @Var CaseAccountIds - to get accountId's of cases with list called CaseIDs */
            set<Id> CaseAccountIds = new set<Id>();
            List<Account> Accountstoupdate =new List<Account>();
            for(Case c : caseTriggers)
            {
                 // Loop through and add AccountId's to the list.
                CaseAccountIds.add(c.AccountId);
            }
     system.debug('CaseAccount IDS ' + CaseAccountIds);
            /** @Var Accountswithcases-to get account details to caluclate average */
            /** @Var results-to get average of particular account based on the cases */
            List<Account> Accountswithcases = [select Id,name,ARPU__c  from Account where id =:CaseAccountIds];
     system.debug('Accounts With Cases ' + accountsWithCases);
            Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
                [SELECT AccountId Id, AVG(ARPU__c) average FROM Case WHERE AccountId = :Accountswithcases GROUP BY AccountId]);
     system.debug('Results ' + results);
            For(account a1: Accountswithcases) 
            {
                if(results.get(a1.Id) != null) 
                {
                    // Loop through aggregate results array and typecast the average of ARPU and update in account level.
 system.debug('Updating Account ARPU ' + a1.ARPU__c);
                    a1.ARPU__c = (Decimal)results.get(a1.Id).get('average');
 system.debug('Updated Account ARPU ' + a1.ARPU__c);

                    Accountstoupdate.add(a1);
                }
                //accSet.addAll(Accountstoupdate);
                //Accountstoupdate.addAll(accSet);
            }
            if(Accountstoupdate.size()>0) 
            {
                // DML statement to update all the accounts related with cases.
 system.debug('Updating Records ' + AccountsToUpdate);

                update Accountstoupdate;
            } 
        }
    }
    }
```

I don't where iam doing wrong

My debug Logs[![Debug Logd][1]][1]

```
  DEBUG|Case:IDS (Case:{Id=500N0000004PhxfIAC, IsDeleted=false,
  CaseNumber=00039404, ContactId=null, AccountId=001N000000r5SmjIAE,
  10:45:20.0 (76512902)|USER_DEBUG|[91]|DEBUG|***TTT****{001N000000r5SmjIAE}
  10:45:20.0 (76600136)|USER_DEBUG|[93]|DEBUG|CaseAccount IDS 
  {001N000000r5SmjIAE}
  10:45:20.0 (97397260)|USER_DEBUG|[97]|DEBUG|Accounts With Cases (Account:
  {Id=001N000000r5SmjIAE, Name=Internal, ARPU__c=8.51})
  10:45:20.0 (122017848)|USER_DEBUG|[101]|DEBUG|Results {}
```

Comment: can you also share your trigger code?

Comment: Hey Sorry i forgot i just shared.@NSjonas

Comment: Sorry to tag but i am running out of time.Can you please look on to this @sfdcfox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure of how everything is calculated, order of operations, and lots going on etc however:

**UPDATE**

Looking at it again, you are performing this query:

```
for(Case c : [SELECT Id,ARPU__c,accountId FROM Case WHERE Id IN :CaseIDs])
            {
                 // Loop through and add AccountId's to the list.
                CaseAccountIds.add(c.AccountId);
            }
```

Which **should** return **NO** records because the cases are deleted and you are querying using the `caseIDs` which are from the trigger.old list.

Which means this query will be empty and the loop updating the accounts will be skipped:

```
List<Account> Accountswithcases = [select Id,name,ARPU__c  from Account where id =:CaseAccountIds];
```

Thus nothing will be updated after that

What you should be doing (I think) is getting the account IDs from the trigger records:

```
for(Case c : caseTriggers)
            {
                 // Loop through and add AccountId's to the list.
                CaseAccountIds.add(c.AccountId);
            }
```

**UPDATE 10-3-2016**

After you made your changes as suggested to use the correct queries and collections, your aggregate result is not returning any rows because there are no more cases associated with the account. In that case you will need to set the value of the account to 0. Like this:

```
if(results.get(a1.id) == null){
     a1.ARPU__c = 0;
}
```

*The following may or may not be relevant depending on the validity of the above*

If you are indeed getting values back from the above (I do not think so but) a possible way to resolve is to exclude Cases explicitly  that pertain to the deleted case thus not pulling in their values during delete

Map results = new Map(
                [SELECT AccountId Id, AVG(ARPU__c) average FROM Case WHERE AccountId = :Accountswithcases  AND ID NOT IN : CaseTriggers  GROUP BY AccountId]);

To know what exactly is going on you will have to use liberal debugs, query for records to see if they exist, examine order of operations, etc. But the above should at least get you the right value

Comment: Thanks.I tried it is not working.i just modified the query in loop as well as aggregate.@Eric

Comment: @Pavantej - I am afraid you are going to have to provide much more detail than "It is not working" Maybe some debug statements that output the collection values, etc. And add the relevant portion of the debug logs to your question.

Comment: Hey Sorry i am working on it.I want to inform you.

Comment: I had posted my logs.But in first for loop query it is still showing of the list has one record.But in end  Accountstoupdate list getting empty. @Eric

Comment: @Pavantej - I added debug lines to your original question. Please add them to your code and then output the debug log in your question. Text version, not image please

Comment: i shared my debug logs.Please look in to that.thanks

Comment: @Pavantej - From the logs it looks like you DID NOT do what I suggested and you are getting the results I mentioned - No CasesWithAccounts. Change your loop to populate that collection using `for(Case c : caseTriggers)` then rerun

Comment: Hi @Eric thanks i had modified after i found my debug logs is i am getting empty from aggregate results array.i am sharing new debug logs also

Comment: @Pavantej - It is because you have no more cases associated with the account. In that case set the value to 0 - See updated answer

Comment: Hey @Eric you are superb i tried same thing but before DML updating.But more than you answer your explanation is superb.you teach so many things.But once again thanks for sharing knowledge.

Comment: @Pavantej - Thank you for the kind words. I am glad that we were able to get this moving forward for you.

Comment: Sorry to disturb but i am facing some issue that is in production allready cases are created with above record type.So, after i moved to the production i mass update all those records with data loader.The issue in aggregate query it calculates average with all cases respective to the account.means it has to calculate average with only arpu cases right.

Comment: i had already raise a new question can you please look on this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143184/trigger-is-not-working-accurately?noredirect=1#comment207644_143184

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void ARPUDelete(List<Case> caseTriggers) {

      if (Trigger.IsDelete){

        /** @Var caseAccountIds - to get accountId's of cases with list called CaseIDs */
        Set<Id> caseAccountIds = new Set<Id>();

        for (Case s : caseTriggers){

          //capture the account ids from trigger.old aka the caseTriggers variable
          if(s.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId && (s.Case_Details__c =='New Subscription' || s.Case_Details__c =='Add On') ) {
            caseAccountIds.add(s.AccountId);
          }

        }

        // list to hold accounts that need updating
        List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

        List<AggregateResult> groupedResults = [SELECT AccountId, AVG(ARPU__c) average 
                                                FROM Case WHERE AccountId = :accountSwithCases 
                                                GROUP BY AccountId]);

        for(AggregateResult ar : groupedResults){
          Id acctId = ar.get('AccountId'); //pull out the account id
          Account theAccount = new Account(); //create a new account object
            theAccount.Id = acctId; //assign the id to the new account object
            theAccount.ARPU__c = (Decimal)ar.get('average'); //populate the ARPU field with the case average

          accountsToUpdate.add(theAccount);
        }

        if( accountsToUpdate.size() > 0 ) {
            // DML statement to update all the accounts where a case was deleted
            update accountsToUpdate;
        } 

      }

    }
```

It seems like you want something like this if the goal is to aggregate the ARPU__c from all the remaining cases for the account after the deletion into a field called ARPU__c on the Account object.  I think the issue your facing now is that in your aggregate map you are using the case Id as your key but then in your for loop are using the account id.

Comment: Any reason for the down vote? I provided the same resolution as @Eric

Comment: I did not give the down vote, but it was most likely because it did not add anything to the answer and essentially just restates a comment. It does not show any effort on your part to provide an answer. Even if it was original it is lacking detail

Comment: I didn't downvote, but often if you post the same answer as someone else well after the fact you will see that happen. Your answer is certainly much improved with all the additional code and explanation.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm new to contributing but have been developing in salesforce for ~5 years, figured it was time to start giving back.  I think I provided more detail for the complete solution this time.

Comment: also that if statement doesn't seem correct to me.  It seems like it should be: if(s.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId && (s.Case_Details__c == 'New Subscription' || s.Case_Details__c =='Add On' )){     I will update the post

Comment: @Goldylocks - Yes you did. I think until we get debug logs though we may be at a standstill. No records should be returned when querying the case object with deleted IDs. Maybe OP left out some code? Debug logs will tell more

Comment: @Eric agreed.  Well I will move on to help others :)  If you find any of my rework helpful I would appreciate an upvote.  I removed the map with the aggregate results, it seems to overcomplicate things.  I would just stick to the traditional way unless the caseIds are being saved in a map somewhere where you can get the deleted case Id to the account Id, otherwise I don't see that working

Comment: @Goldylocks - Very useful. I am ecstatic that you are contributing and providing so much detail in your answer. Its refreshing to see a new face thinking through the their answer and willing to help others. I look forward to your future contributions. See you at 100K soon :)

Comment: I am trying to modify my code as per your answer But it is not working.even it throws an error Id acctId = (Id)ar.get('AccountId'); //pull out the account id.so, i typecast above one.But till it not updating account.@Goldylocks

Comment: i shared my debug logs.Please look in to that.thanks @Goldylocks