# Trigger is not working accurately

Tags: apex, soql, record-type

got a requirement like to calculate average in account based on particular record type of case. My requirement is:

I have a field called ARP in account currency. I want to calculate overall average of ARP field in particular record type called customer order whether Case details either new or add-on.

So I'm trying write a trigger a trigger.

Everything is working fine in sandbox but in production when i update any old cases it's not updating accurately.If i do update in sandbox is working fine.

And for example there is case with above criteria like 18.55.But it updating 6.55.When i check from random accounts it  is calculating average with all cases to a respective account.

When i try to create any cases with new accounts it is working fine.Please help me guys to sort out.

I tried to check from debug logs it is calculating average with all cases with respective to an account.But, i didn't understood i wrote the query to calculate only respective cases only.

It is not working on if cases already created on an account

```
trigger ForARPU on case (after insert,after update,after delete) 
{
   if(Trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isAfter && 
    trigger.isUpdate) 
{     
    //It will call a static method called ARPUInsert in ARPUCases class.
    ARPUCases.ARPUInsert(Trigger.New);

}
}
```

Handler trigger

```
   public static void ARPUInsert(List<Case>  CaseTriggers)
{
    /** 
     * This method is to caluclate average of all ARPU amounts with case have customer order recordtype
     * as well as case details with either ADD-On (OR) New Subscription and update in related account
     * field called ARPU. 
     * This method will fire only when any case with record type called customer order is created as well updated. 
    */
    Id recordTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'Customer_Order'].Id;
    List<Account> Accountstoupdate =new List<Account>();
    List<Case> CaseIDs = new List<Case>();
    for (Case s : CaseTriggers)
    {
        if(s.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId && (s.Case_Details__c =='New Subscription' || s.Case_Details__c =='Add On') ) 
        {
                // Loop through and add caseId's to the list.
                CaseIDs.add(s);
        }
    }
    /** @Var CaseAccountIds - to get accountId's of cases with list called CaseIDs */
    set<Id> CaseAccountIds = new set<Id>();
    for(Case c : [SELECT Id,ARPU__c,accountId FROM Case WHERE Id IN :CaseIDs 
                  AND(recordTypeId =:recordTypeId AND (Case_Details__c ='New 
                  Subscription' OR Case_Details__c ='Add On')])
    {
        // Loop through and add AccountId's to the list.
        CaseAccountIds.add(c.AccountId);
    }
    /** @Var Accountswithcases-to get account details to caluclate average */
    /** @Var results-to get average of particular account based on the cases */
    List<Account> Accountswithcases = [select Id,name,ARPU__c  from Account where id =:CaseAccountIds];
   Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
         [SELECT AccountId Id, AVG(ARPU__c) average FROM Case WHERE
          AccountId =:Accountswithcases AND(recordTypeId =:recordTypeId AND 
         (Case_Details__c ='New Subscription' OR Case_Details__c ='Add On')) 
          GROUP BY AccountId]);
    For(account a1: Accountswithcases) 
    {
        if(results.get(a1.Id) != null) 
        {
            // Loop through aggregate results array and typecast the average of ARPU and update in account level.
            a1.ARPU__c = (Decimal)results.get(a1.Id).get('average');
            Accountstoupdate.add(a1);
        }
    }
    if(Accountstoupdate.size()>0) 
    {
        // DML statement to update all the accounts related with cases
        update Accountstoupdate;
    }
    }
```

Comment: you are not using `CaseIDs` list in your code. maybe you need to query Account based on this list

Comment: Hey @TusharSharma it's calculating average of all cases with respective account.How to restrict to calculate average of all cases .

Comment: Hey @TusharSharma i am updated my code as well as my question can you please look on to this

Comment: Add a filter to your case query for the recordtype.name = 'customer_order' to only include those cases with that record type

Comment: What is the use we are already filtering the above caseIds list with only those record type and other criteria.@Eric AnD updated my code with our suggestion but it is not updating anything even when i create any new case it not updating anything.let me any changes i didn't done correctly

Comment: Hey sorry @Eric i updated in wrong query.I just updated my code it works charm like recordtypeid as well as other criteria.If i didn't include other criteria it is calculating all cases with those recordtypes. Please update your answer i will close the question.

Comment: @Pavantej - Answer added per your request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a filter to your case query for the `recordtype.name = 'customer_order'` to only include those cases with that record type.

```
Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
        [SELECT AccountId Id, AVG(ARPU__c) average FROM Case WHERE AccountId 
         =:Accountswithcases AND(recordTypeId =:recordTypeId AND (Case_Details__c ='New 
          Subscription' OR Case_Details__c ='Add On')) GROUP BY AccountId]);
```

Comment: Then why did you ask me to post it as an answer???? Just because you needed additional criteria does not mean this is not an answer as if got you to the right place. Answers cannot possibly include all parameters especially if they are not in your original question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to say.But when i try to customize above query in my case is not working and even it can't update in account.Because my problem calculating average.so, i try to filter in aggregate query but your suggestion works for me that's why i am asking to post answer.Thank you once again and you are life saver .And i am unable to invite for private chat.

Comment: @Paven - I copied the query directly from your question. Can you please edit my answer with the query you used then?

Comment: Sorry @Eric i thought i had updated my question.It's my mistake thank you once again.